# How to set a value into a linq in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I am very new with lambda expressions. I want to have the count of all the status_ID who has the number 6. Then I want to convert this as a list. What is the right syntax to set a value to the query? I know it in SQL but not in lambda expressions.

```
return ContextHelperSlowly<Moi>.GetCount(false, x => x.Status_ID == 6).ToList();
```

Kind regards

Update

```
  public static int GetCount(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        int list;
        using (var context = GetContext())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
            if (null != navigationProperties)
            {
                foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                {
                    dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);
                }
            }
            if (null == where)
            {
                where = arg => true;
            }
            list = dbQuery
                .Where(x => x.Date_Deleted == null && x.End_Validity == null)
                .Where(where)
                .Count();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste GetCounts definition?

Comment: Count will be an integer

Comment: There you go @kuskmen

Comment: Yeah I am sorry gonna change the post @ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: Why you want the count as list?

Comment: So I can bind it to a chart in Highcharts the values the aspect is a serie object like [1, 3, 6]

Comment: `int GetCount(....)` means you are doing `int.ToList()` in the first snippet.

Comment: @Fearcoder so you want to call multiple times this `GetCount` method and save the results in list?

Comment: yes sir @kuskmen

Comment: Can you post the whole function where you call `GetCount` as well, and will predicate change? I mean if you are only searching for `status_id = 6` it will return most of the times the same thing right or you want to change this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to write those functions yourself?

this gives you the number of items with Status_ID = 6:

```
yourList.Count(x => x.Status_ID == 6);
```

and this gives you a list of all entries with Status_ID = 6:

```
yourList.Where(x => x.Status_ID == 6).ToList();
```

And a little notice for "code style". You can do this however you want, but C# standard would be "StatusId" for a property.

Comment: If you are just doing it to learn lambda, then please continue. I just think it is very complex for such an easy task.

Comment: looks like OP is trying to query a database through entity framework. It's not about the lambda expression.

Comment: You might be right about that. Still the code looks a little too circumstantial for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change your GetCount method to GetList:

```
public static List<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    using (var context = GetContext())
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
        if (null != navigationProperties)
        {
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            {
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);
            }
        }
        if (null == where)
        {
            where = arg => true;
        }
        return dbQuery
            .Where(x => x.Date_Deleted == null 
                     && x.End_Validity == null
                     && where(x))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And use:

```
return ContextHelperSlowly<Moi>.GetList(false, x => x.Status_ID == 6);
```

To get the count as an int:

```
return ContextHelperSlowly<Moi>.GetList(false, x => x.Status_ID == 6).Count;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time I tried your solution and get a error cannot convert lambda expressions because its not a delegate type

Comment: ok. I have edited the where bit. Your're passing in a function accepting x as a parameter and returning a bool so it needs to be used as such.